# Multicompany Security Permissions. (Odoo 12)

Tags: python, odoo

I want to set permissions for users by company, for example ,

> user('X') : 'Manager' in Purchases (Company A)
> user('X') : 'Not Manager' in
> Purchases (Company B)

So , when the user is connecting with (Company A), has the possibility to access to purchase menu.
and when is connecting with (Company B), does not has the possibility to access to purchase menu.

Any help please how can I do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible in odoo by default for that you have to code or use third party apps for example: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/multicompany_groups/

Comment: Yes, my question was about coding,... an idea how to do it by code. @AdamStrauss

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available in Odoo standard.

I recommend using the "User Roles" module, that supports per company access group configuration:

https://odoo-community.org/shop/product/user-roles-714?search=user_role